# Are Movie companion books on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Movie companion books, as I personally define them, are books that are released in conjunction with (or after) the release of a movie, maybe even sometimes before.  They typically add information about characters, plot, settings, or other aspects about the movie or the universe the movies was set in.

These books aren't necessarily 100% dependent on seeing the movie first, and can be good sources of information.

See my a question here: [Why was the Obscurus omitted?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/117/why-was-the-obscurus-omitted).  It's admittedly not a great question in itself, but that shouldn't be condemning for ALL companion books.

So, what do we think about companion books, or other pieces of literature written to accompany a movie?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are movie Character guides ontopic?](http://meta.literature.stackexchange.com/questions/77/are-movie-character-guides-ontopic)

Comment: @Himarm I'd argue mine's broader

Comment: It seems such "companion books" are largely non-fiction and don't tell an actual story at all. I doubt a pop-science book on gravitation would be on-topic, just because it has the word "Interstellar" in the title.

Comment: @ChristianRau Yes, so what? Literature doesn't *have* to tell a story.

Comment: @Gilles *That*, I guess, makes for an interesting meta discussion on its own.

Answer (score 2):

I personally think they are On-topic.  They are a good source of information for those that want to READ more about a particular universe.

I also don't think we want to get into the weeds of "this type of book is off-topic because it's for a movie" and "this graphic novel is off-topic because it extends a movie universe" and such.

Comment: No, if anything, it's off-topic because it's a non-fictional non-storytelling encyclopedia.

Comment: @ChristianRau it's not exactly like an encyclopedia, but it's not straight up story telling either, it's a mix of both.