# What sorts of identification questions about nonfiction works are on-topic? For example, are cookbooks on topic? How about sex manuals?

Tags: discussion, scope

I voted to close the [identification-question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-question) [Book about Tantric Sex Written by an Australian Couple that uses the terms 'Lingam' and 'Yoni'](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/25849/book-about-tantric-sex-written-by-an-australian-couple-that-uses-the-terms-ling) on the grounds that the work in question did not qualify as literature within the scope defined in the [help center](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help):

> We interpret ‘literature’ in a broad sense, including written, spoken and sung works, in all genres, languages and forms: poetry, plays, stories, novels, lyrics, comic books, essays, belles-lettres, and so on.

As written, the scope seems to refers to *imaginative* literature. The term "literature" is not defined as encompassing any and every verbal production. Rather, it specifies works of a type that one could broadly categorize as "literary". This specification does not appear to include, say, textbooks, newspaper articles, or a boy band fan blog.

The meta question [What types of non-fiction are on topic?](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-types-of-non-fiction-are-on-topic) both broadens and clarifies that scope. The top rated [answer](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/184/289) there, by BESW, says:

> For anything that we can ask a literary question about, such questions are on topic for the purposes of site scope. There are lots of questions about literature which aren't literary questions, and lots of literary questions about things which conventional academic wisdom might not consider literature.

In another well-received [answer](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1183/289), Gareth Rees writes:

> If the question is primarily about the choice of words, or the meaning of a passage, or the use of rhetorical devices, or the prose style, or how to interpret difficult or ambiguous parts of the text, or about the source of an allusion or quotation, and so on, then it is a literary question and belongs here, regardless of the nature of the text.

On the basis of the preceding, it seems that a question asking merely for an *identification* of a work that does not have any pretensions to being literary in its import would be off-topic. I'm using "literary" here in the same sense that BESW and Gareth do in the quoted portions above. If I ask for a particular story, poem, comic, etc. to be identified, well, that's in scope. If I ask about the use of language or rhetoric within a book about tantra, that's in scope. But should a question like "what is this tantra book?" be treated as in scope, absent any evidence that the book in question lends itself to literary discussion?

I have the same issue with [Identify a cookbook with a Deputy preparing a whole camel](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/25320/identify-a-cookbook-with-a-deputy-preparing-a-whole-camel). The question asks for the identification of a cookbook based on a photograph (with no indication where the photograph is from), and the only answer says (correctly) that the photograph is a frame from a movie. Is that within scope?

Valorum [commented](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/25849/book-about-tantric-sex-written-by-an-australian-couple-that-uses-the-terms-ling#comment39417_25849) upon my close vote on the tantra book question that the book falls under the OED definition of literature as "books and writings published on a particular subject". But if we go by that definition, then **any** [identification-question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-question) about any book on any subject is in scope here, because the book is literature on a particular subject: tantra, cookery, jumping rope, cable TV, spiders, quantum physics ... is that what we want?

Answer (score 2):

There's always been a tension around these kinds of questions which is not straightforward to resolve. As moderators, we aspire to creating hard rules as to what is on- and off-topic to make it easier to guide users and to make decisions on individual questions. However, like a lot of arts-based subjects, this puts us in a bit of a bind.

It's very tempting to simply state that we don't take questions on works of non-fiction, which would seem to solve a lot of problems. I know that early on in this site there was a discussion about the value of literary analysis of works of non-fiction which and the consensus was that there was value - an interpretation that I, personally, don't agree with. My recollection is that the consensus very much included textbooks, newspaper articles, and boy band fan blogs. However, even if we leave that contention aside, disallowing questions on non-fiction means no discussion of academic work around literary theory and the like, which feels like a huge omission.

So if we can't disallow questions about non-fiction, what hard criteria can we find to draw the line in the sand that disallows sex guides and cookbooks? We could look at those (and other) categories of book and specifically disallow those that we don't want, but we immediately run into trouble over what is, or is not, a sex guide or a cookbook. There is, for example, a wholly fictional cookery book called *A Traveler's Guide to The Lucky Gryphon: Recipes & Regalings*. I doubt it's a volume of much literary merit, but can we really exclude it because we don't want cookbooks? You could make a similar argument about sex guides and the *Kama Sutra*.

If we start using criteria like "imaginative" or "literary" then we're on a similar slippery slope, which - however much I'd love these to be criteria for inclusion in this community - is equally hard to define and smacks badly of elitism. There is value to be had in dissecting all but the most tawdry pulp fiction, even if that value is chiefly helping people toward better reading.

Which essentially leaves us with the 1964 supreme court's porn definition, "I shall not today attempt further to define the kinds of material I understand to be embraced... [b]ut I know it when I see it ...". I would agree the questions highlighted in this meta-question should be off-topic and I would agree to close them. The wider question is, are we happy to proceed using this rather flimsy definition of what belongs and essentially leaving it up to the whims of individual moderators?

Comment: *"essentially leaving it up to the whims of individual moderators"* - if we interpret this to mean content moderators (e.g. anyone who can VTC) rather than diamond moderators, it's not so bad. It takes five people to actually close or reopen a question as off-topic, so we can leave it to the collective whims of the high-rep community, and in this way a sort of de facto consensus may be formed over time.

Answer (score 0):

**I am in favor of allowing all identification questions <sup>1</sup>.**

Identification questions are really an almost separate entity when it comes to scope. Whatever rules we apply to other types of questions can be difficult to apply. In part because we cannot fully know what type of work the target of identification is until has been successfully identified. Maybe the part we remember about "maths and a fractal" is actually the Jurassic Park novel, maybe the recipe we remember was actually part of spell book?

Since we have no genre scope (e.g., Science Fiction and Fantasy), and we allow scholastic questions on fiction and non-fiction alike, there should no reason why asking to identify any work is off-topic. To do otherwise seems [exclusionary and elitist](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/300/56), which this site has [wrestled with before](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/898/our-site-can-be-cold-unforgiving-and-unapproachable-were-driving-people-away).

Given that Literature is small site with a fairly large scope and target audience we should be as welcoming as we can. If we have a slew of low quality posts we should as community to improve (or remove) them, but looking at the list of questions only a few have a negative score. If you do not like identification questions at all, you can simply ignore the tag to allow better access to the types of questions you want to ask, answer, or read.

<sup>1 - so long as it literature (i.e. any written work) and not a movie, video game, or "object identification".</sup>

Comment: Your footnote makes this answer essentially dodge the main question. What is "literature" and what are "things that would [be] wholly off-topic to begin with" - and isn't that kind of the point? If cookbooks are wholly off-topic to begin with, then this would mean making cookbook ID off-topic, but I don't think that's what you are arguing here?

Comment: @Randal'Thor I mean things that are not in a written medium at all. I hesitated to say"music/songs" because we've allowed lyric questions based on them being a form poetry.  I meant more like we won't identify objects (tools, cars, planes, animals etc.). I added the footnote because I knew someone would be pedantic and say "ALL identification... what's this bird I saw in my garden".

Comment: I'm not against the principle of this answer (it seems to be what we do for [tag:quote-source], allowing the IDing of quotes from any kind of even non-literary source that we wouldn't allow other types of questions about), but you need to explain better where you're proposing to draw the line, otherwise the footnote takes us straight back to square 1.